# iOS - last character disappears in when saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am implementing the following method to save data of text field in case of change to `_detailsDictionary` ,but when it saves ,the last letter enterd in textfield.text doesn't appear,e.g if I am saving `Krish`,then only `kris` will be saved.How thids can be fixxed?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSInteger field = textField.tag;

    if(field ==1)
    {

        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"FName"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"FName"];
        }
        return YES;
            }
    if(field ==2)
    {


        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"MName"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"MName"];
        }

         return YES;
    }

    if(field ==3)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"LName"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"LName"];
        }
         return YES;
    }

    if(field ==4)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"City"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"City"];
        }
         return YES;
    }

    if(field ==5)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"State"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"State"];
     }
         return YES;
    }

    if(field ==6)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Country"];
        }
         return YES;
    }

    if(field ==7)
    {

        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"DOB"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"DOB"];
        }
         return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: call your function in textfieled endediting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method you will not get the full text from `textfield.text` as this methods get called before text actually enters in `textfield`

You need to use

```
NSString *strText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

here in `strText` you will get fullText

Comment: Hii...how can I stop keyboard from working on txtfield 7 additionally?

Comment: Not getting you properly what you want to achieve, If you simply want to make textField7 interaction disable then you can set `textField7.isUserInteractionEnabled = NO;`

Comment: I actually want to open a date picker on textfield 7 .So ,i want keybord to not work in that case ,but if i do return no ..then it doesn't save data selected from date picker in my dictionary.

Comment: You can save data in your dictionary while getting the value from picker

Answer (score 1):

It's known that `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` function is used to make changes to the `textfield` before the character being written is appended to the actual string.
So when you are trying to get the text from the `textfield` in this function, the last character is not yet added to the string.

So instead of using this function, use this one `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

Answer (score 0):

I am using rajat's answer here with little more details.
First you need to take the full text:

```
NSString *strText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

then you have to add the `strText`to your dictionary instead of `textField.text`

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this if you are storing data in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` mathod.

```
NSString *fname = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
[_detailsDictionary setObject:fname forKey:@"FName"];
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSInteger field = textField.tag;

    if(field ==1)
    {

        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"FName"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"FName"];
        }

            }
    if(field ==2)
    {


        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"MName"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"MName"];
        }


    }

    if(field ==3)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"LName"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"LName"];
        }

    }

    if(field ==4)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"City"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"City"];
        }

    }

    if(field ==5)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"State"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"State"];
     }

    }

    if(field ==6)
    {
        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"Country"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Country"];
        }

    }

    if(field ==7)
    {

        if(textField.text ==[_detailsDictionary valueForKey:@"DOB"])
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"DOB"];
        }

    }

}
```